# UITapGestureRecognizer for image picker not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Trying to create an image picker with a tap gesture, so when the default picture is tapped it allows the user to pick an image from the device's photo library. For some reason when I click the view in the iOS simulator it simply doesn't do anything and I can't figure out why.

This is what I have so far. I'm pretty new to Objective-C

ViewController.m :

```
#import "ViewController.h"

interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *nameField;   
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *brandField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *priceField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField    *additionalNotesField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *addItem;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *cancelAdditem;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *toyImage;
- (IBAction)imageSelect:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender;


@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
 [super viewDidLoad];

_nameField.delegate = self;
_brandField.delegate = self;
_priceField.delegate = self;
_additionalNotesField.delegate = self;

// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

 -(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *) textField {

    textField.resignFirstResponder;

    return true;
}

-(void) textFieldDidEndEditing:( UITextField *) textField {
    _nameField.text = textField.text;
    _brandField.text = textField.text;
    _priceField.text = textField.text;
    _additionalNotesField.text = textField.text;
}

- (IBAction)imageSelect:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {

// Hide the keyboard
  _nameField.resignFirstResponder;
  _brandField.resignFirstResponder;
  _priceField.resignFirstResponder;

UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init]; // Creates image picker

imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary; // Source for picker is saved photos. Only allow photos to be picked, not taken

// Make sure the picker is notified when the user picks an image
imagePicker.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:true completion:nil];

}

// UIImagePickerControllerDelegete

-(void) imagePickerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *) imagePicker {

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:true completion:nil]; // Dimiss the picker if the user canceled
}

-(void) imagePicker:(UIImagePickerController *) picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{

 UIImage* selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

 _toyImage.image = selectedImage; // Set the image view to display the selected image 

// Dimiss the picker
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:true completion:nil];
}

@end
```

Comment: By default, a `UIImageView` `isUserInteractionEnabled `property is `false` and should then block user action.

Comment: That seemed to do the trick, many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Larme said, I needed to add this line:

```
_toyImage.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```